# Can I listen Priscilla's song again in Witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3

How to listen Priscilla's song again without loading of saves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you can do it in game (If my memory is right, she is attacked shortly after her performance and loses her voice), but feel free to find it on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bSk-8C76dc). There is even a cleverly made [multi-language version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67FVWoyRWo8)